# How do I find out the address of [Settings>Display->Cast] devices?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, screencast, miracast

I see a `[TV] Samsung 6 Series (50)` wireless display in the list from display settings. But I do not own a Samsung television, so I would like to know the IP or MAC address of this device to double check with my router's list of connected devices.

Comment: Its just detecting  a device compatible with WiDi and not necessarily connected to it besides it doesn't require an access point.

Comment: So it's not inside the LAN ?

Comment: Its more like bluetooth technology (thinking backwardly) you can't really identify a device's bluetooth MAC let alone without even made  connection/pairing. It is just scanned and put on a list of available devices

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily identify its MAC address as its not connected to any AP.

Wireless display (WiDi) **does not require** any Wi-Fi Access Point or router or hotspot for operation. It uses WiFi Direct® (or Wi-Fi CERTIFIED™ Miracast®) technology, for wireless connection to WiDi compliant receiver.

Having said that, it therefore implies that by your device identifying `[TV] Samsung 6 Series (50)` in Settings→ Display →Cast is not connected to any AP, but it just being detected by your device as a "nearby device" and does not even reveal its MAC/IP explicitly even if you make the connection.

---

However the easiest way to identify its MAC/IP is allowing it to connect to any of available wireless AP:

- Go to your TV's menu and choose Network → Network Settings
- Choose Wireless for your connection type
- Choose to connect to the  `SSID`
- At this point, the Smart TVs will show you a screen with the Wireless MAC address.
- If not, go back to the Menu and choose Network → Network Status.

Alternatively check on your device's list of connected devices and get the IP.

---

Note: I have even observed that my Smart TV (Samsung) shows in the list of Available Wireless Display devices on my tablet, even before connection.